# How to register serilog in startup.cs file in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am upgrading project from .NET 5 to .NET 6. In NET5 I have register serilog like below

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, Type startupType) =>
                  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                   {
                     config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true);
                    })
                    .UseSerilog() // set Serilog as the logging provider
                    .UseStartup(startupType);
```

In .NET 6 I am getting error that UseSerilog needs to be used at IHostBuilder. Most of examples to register UseSerilog is in program.cs file. I need to register this in Startup.cs file only. Program.cs file is not there in project.

Comment: This particular code also part of program.cs in .NET 5.  I am little surprised that you dont have program.cs, where is your main method then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 6, there is only one `Program.cs` file by default, and `Startup.cs` is cancelled.

If you want to keep using the `Startup.cs` file and configure serilog in it, you can refer to my test code below:

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration configRoot{ get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            configRoot = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();
            Log.Information("Starting up");

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            
        }
        public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services,builder.Environment); // calling ConfigureServices method
var app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(app, builder.Environment, app.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()); // calling Configure method
```

Don't forget to install the corresponding NuGet package(`Serilog.AspNetCore`, `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting`, `Serilog.Sinks.Seq`):
[image]

Test Result:

[image]